# clear and enable/disable fields based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to clear the values of the field and enable / disable the fields based on the drop down value selection. Currently enable / disable of the fields are working but when it comes to clear the field its not working.
I have attached the snippet from my html code where based on status value the other fields like sc, sc raised etc should enable. Based on the status value change the prev enabled field should clear. And even submit button should enable based on it. Any help?

Html code snippet:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Status:<span class="Imp">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
         @Html.DropDownList("Status", new SelectListItem[] { (new SelectListItem() { Text = "SC", Value = "SC" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "PO", Value = "PO" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "INV", Value = "INV" }) }, "-- Select Status --", new { @class = "form-control", id = "Status" })
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row top-buffer">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-lg-4">SC Raised:<span class="Imp">*</span></label>
         <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class='input-group date' id='SCRaisedDatePicker'>
               <input type='text' class="form-control" name="SCRaised" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" id="SCRaised" />
               <span class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="fa fa-calendar">
               </span>
               </span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-lg-4">SC:<span class="Imp">*</span></label>
         <div class="col-lg-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.detailsConfig.SC, new { onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)", @class = "form-control", id = "SC" })
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row top-buffer">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-lg-4">PO#:<span class="Imp">*</span></label>
         <div class="col-lg-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.detailsConfig.PO, new { onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)", @class = "form-control", id = "PO" })
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-lg-4">PO Out:<span class="Imp">*</span></label>
         <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class='input-group date' id='PODatePicker'>
               <input type='text' class="form-control" name="POOut" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" id="POOut" />
               <span class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="fa fa-calendar">
               </span>
               </span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
   <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
</div>
```

java script code:

```
$('#Status').change(function() {

    switch ($(this).find('option:selected').text()) {

        case '-- Select Status --':
            $('#SCRaised').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#SC').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#PO').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#POOut').prop('disabled', true);

            break;

        case 'SC':
            $('#SCRaised').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#SC').prop('disabled', false);

            document.getElementById("#PO").value = "";
            document.getElementById("#POOut").value = "";



            $('#PO').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#POOut').prop('disabled', true);

            if ($('#SCRaised').val().length > 0 && $('#SC').val().length > 0) {
                $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
            }

            break;

        case 'PO':
            $('#PO').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#POOut').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#SCRaised').val() = "";
            $('#SC').val() = "";


            $('#SCRaised').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#SC').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#ItemArrival').prop('disabled', true);
            if ($('#PO').val().length > 0 &&
                $('#POOut').val().length > 0)

            {
                $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
            }
            break;


    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you with a solution

```js
$('#Status').change(function () {

  switch($(this).find('option:selected').text()){

    case '-- Select Status --':                 
      $('#SCRaised, #SC, #PO, #POOut').prop('disabled',true);
      break;

    case 'SC' :   
      $('#SCRaised, #SC').prop('disabled', false);
      $("#PO, #POOut").val('');
      $('#PO, #POOut').prop('disabled', true);

      if ($('#SCRaised').val().length > 0 && $('#SC').val().length > 0) {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
      }

      break;

    case 'PO' :
      $('#PO, #POOut').prop('disabled', false);
      $('#SCRaised, #SC').val('');
      $('#SCRaised, #SC, #ItemArrival').prop('disabled', true);
      if(  $('#PO').val().length > 0 && $('#POOut').val().length > 0){
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
      }
      break;
  }
});
```

Hope this will help you to fix the problem & reduce the number of lines of code.

Comment: the submit doesn't get enabled even if i enter values into SCRaised and SC. Rest of the things work fine:) Any help with above issue

Comment: Please add console.log inside if statement, and check if it's going inside if statement.

Comment: i checked its not entering if statement and even throwing error in console "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: You are getting an error, even after I edited the code??? Both the selections  ('SC' & 'PO') are giving the same error?

Comment: what is the edit in you code? I checked for SC and I am getting the error

Comment: Mistake was `$('#SCRaised, #SC').val() = "";`. Change the code to `$('#SCRaised, #SC').val();`

Comment: Oh but I had already made this change and tried it. Error is with if statement. "Length" seems to be giving an issue..

Comment: console.log( $('#SCRaised').val()); check what you are getting?

Comment: This is a basic example created for your reference https://jsfiddle.net/mmh5n2kd/

Comment: No i couldn't. looks like datepicker is an issue. Anyway the your solution works for input fields. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

The one thing I noticed in your code snippet is that you are using `getElementById` incorrectly.

```
document.getElementById("#PO").value = "";
```

As an argument you should provide the id without `#`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the value from a input use the jquery `val()` function pass a empty string as a aprama

`$('#SCRaised').val('');`

Answer (score 0):

instent of using change - $('#Status').change(function() 
use on - `$('#Status').on('change',function() {})` and for clearing the value use

```
$('#PO').val("")
```

rather than document.getElementById("#PO").value = ""; as mentioned earlier by mic4ael no need to use **#** selection in javascript code.